# Upload and position image into Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I place an uploaded logo into a Cognito form, in a desired location, with the alignment I would like?

I've created a form and uploaded a logo to include in the form but can't find how to place or align the logo in the form.

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Although this is not currently supported. This is a wonderful idea that we are in the process of looking into. Users should have the ability to align the logo when updated to their form. We have added this to our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/YBnu0cLi). You will be able to track this features progress there.

In the meantime before this feature is released, if you are embedding your form on your website you can use CSS to control the position of your logo.